# ADODB error: 'No value given for one or more required parameters'

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I am trying to get some data from another excel spreadsheet, using ADODB and VBA. This is my first attempt at using ADODB, I apologize for my ignorance.

THIS WORKS at pulling all the data from the sheet:

```
rst1.Open "SELECT * FROM [NAVAUM$A1:IU60000];", cnn1, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```

THIS WORKS at getting the fields I want, but no Field Names:

```
rst1.Open "SELECT F2,F3 FROM [NAVAUM$A2:IU60000] WHERE F1 = 'Return' AND F3 LIKE '" & SearchString & "';", cnn1, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```

THIS DOES NOT WORK

```
rst1.Open "SELECT F2,F3 FROM [NAVAUM$A1:IU60000] WHERE F1 = 'Return' AND F3 LIKE '" & SearchString & "';", cnn1, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```

(The difference is the inclusion of row 1, where the field names are.)

It should be noted that row 2 is all blank. (This is how the file comes to me, cannot be changed.) How do I fix this???

EDIT: I GOT THIS!!!

I did not change the query to reflect the fact that I actually have field names now. So, F2 and F3 become [Fund ID] and [Fund Name]. I am not bright.

Thanks for knocking the screw loose StackOverflow!!

Comment: You can add your solution as an answer then accept it after a short delay

Comment: @lukehawk No, you ARE bright! You persisted and you've figured it out youself--that's the best learning experience. More to come, I am sure :)

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks, I did not realize I could do this. I fix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out... I did not change the query to reflect the fact that I actually have field names now. So, F2 and F3 become [Fund ID] and [Fund Name]. (F1 is still not named in my data.) 
I am not bright.

Thanks for knocking the screw loose StackOverflow!!

THIS...

```
rst1.Open "SELECT F2,F3 FROM [NAVAUM$A1:IU60000] WHERE F1 = 'Return' AND F3 LIKE '" & SearchString & "';", cnn1, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```

SHOULD BE...

```
rst1.Open "SELECT [Fund ID],[Fund Name] FROM [NAVAUM$A1:IU60000] WHERE F1 = 'Return' AND [Fund Name] LIKE '" & SearchString & "';", cnn1, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```

Thanks again!